# Copying changes from one cell to another across worksheets based on 2 criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where multiple people are making entries into a database (sheet1) and have code that copies the entries to new worksheets base on who entered the data (Person1,Person2,Person3, etc.)

The code that is being used move the entries is:

```
 Sub MoveAdokpa()
 With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Sheet1.Activate

Dim RNG As Range

 Set RNG = Range([C1], Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

On Error Resume Next
With RNG
.AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:="Adokpa"
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
Sheets("Alice Adokpa").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormulas)

.AutoFilter
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

On each users specified worksheet they are required to make changes on their entries depending on where they are in the process we are tracking.

The worksheet needs to be able to take the changes the user made on their individual worksheets and export the updated information BACK to the Sheet1 database. However, the entries on the Sheet1 database are in no particular order. I am thinking that I could possibly write something that identifies 2 criteria (I.E. User's Name and Entry ID number) and then moves the changes made to the row on the user's sheet to the Sheet1 entry with the matching criteria. I do not know how to write this though and have found no examples online that I can follow.

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: You could record a macro, go to the data tab, click sort, stop recording then learn from the output. I know that may come across as blunt but it is meant to be helpful.

Comment: One approach is to read the data on `Sheet1` into a `Variant` array and then loop over it until you find the row that matches the 2 criteria. I would strongly advise against using Excel as a "database" though. It's not meant for this sort of thing.